# Android Espresso setup in Intellij Idea IDE

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, android-espresso

Can anybody help in me setting up Espresso in Intellij idea IDE for testing Android apps? Any instructions or tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This example should help. Though I'm still working through the details myself.

https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template